# Renaming Foreign Key - Sequelize and MySQL

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

[Resolved !]

I want to rename foreign key in JavaScript level. I have two tables `roles` and `users` in MySQL database.

`roles`
`role_id, name, description, created_at, updated_at`

`users`
`user_id, username, password, role_id, created_at, updated_at`

Below is my `User` Model.

```
"use strict";

const { Model } = require("sequelize");

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      User.belongsTo(models.Role, {
        foreignKey: {
          allowNull: false,
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          name: "role_id",
        },
        onDelete: "NO ACTION",
        onUpdate: "CASCADE",
      });
    }
  }

  User.init(
    {
      userId: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        field: "user_id",
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      },
      username: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
      },
      password: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        field: "created_at",
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        field: "updated_at",
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
      },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      tableName: "users",
      modelName: "User",
    }
  );

  return User;
};
```

When I `findAll()` to `User`, it give me following result.

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "username": "Jovanny44@yahoo.com",
    "password": "2xRRVUz8DZUENrd",
    "createdAt": "2020-07-20T11:09:05.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-07-20T11:09:05.000Z",
    "role_id": 1
},
...
```

> **What I want**

I want that `role_id` key as `roleId`.

> **What I've tried - 1**

```
static associate(models) {
      User.belongsTo(models.Role, {
        foreignKey: {
          allowNull: false,
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          name: "role_id",
          as: "roleId",
        },
        onDelete: "NO ACTION",
        onUpdate: "CASCADE",
      });
    }
```

***Result:*** No effect

> **What I've tried - 2**

```
User.init(
    {
      userId: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        field: "user_id",
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      },
      username: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
      },
      password: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      },
      roleId: { // ---------------------> I added this.
        allowNull: false,
        field: "role_id",
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        field: "created_at",
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        field: "updated_at",
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
      },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      tableName: "users",
      modelName: "User",
    }
  );
```

***Result:***

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "username": "Jovanny44@yahoo.com",
    "password": "2xRRVUz8DZUENrd",
    "roleId": 1,
    "createdAt": "2020-07-20T11:09:05.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-07-20T11:09:05.000Z",
    "role_id": 1
}
```

> **What I have to do**

I need that association (belongsTo, in this case) for eager loading. By the way, eager loading is working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using sequelize **v6**.

Define the foreign key on the model and target it with `foreignKey` on associate.

```
"use strict";

const { Model } = require("sequelize");

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      User.belongsTo(models.Role, {
        foreignKey: "roleId",
      });
    }
  }

  User.init(
    {
      userId: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        field: "user_id",
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      },
      username: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
      },
      password: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      },
      roleId: {
        allowNull: false,
        field: "role_id",
        references: {
          model: "roles",
          key: "role_id",
        },
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        field: "created_at",
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        field: "updated_at",
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
      },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      tableName: "users",
      modelName: "User",
    }
  );

  return User;
};
```